# Yii2 - how to set main config param pagination pageSizeLimit?

Tags: php, pagination, yii2, config

I want set main config param pageSizeLimit in class Pagination.

Example: (/backend/config/main.php)

```
'pagination' => [
        'class' => 'yii\data\Pagination',
        [
            'pageSizeLimit' => [1, 1000],
        ]
    ],
```

But it not working.
So, how to set defaults for the entire site?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use dependency injection container for this purpose.

Define default parameter's value in bootstrapping section of config:

```
\Yii::$container->set('yii\data\Pagination', [
    'pageSizeLimit' => [1, 1000],
]);
```

Read more on this in the guide https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/concept-configurations.md

Answer (score 3):

Make your own `Pagination` class inherited from `\yii\data\Pagination` and in it set `pageSizeLimit` to whatever value you want. Then use this class in your data providers.

```
namespace app\components;

class Pagination extends \yii\data\Pagination
{
    $defaultPageSize = 100;
    $pageSizeLimit = [1, 1000];
}
```

Then in your data providers:

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query,
    'pagination' => [
        'class' => '\app\components\Pagination'
    ],
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

As of 2.0.11, you can add this to the `container` config section via dependency injection:

```
'container' => [
    'definitions' => [
        'yii\data\Pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 5,
        ],
    ],
],
```